# Change Preview Highlighter color

Tags: macos, preview, color

is there a way to change the highlighter colors back before capitan update? better yet, choose your own colors

i loved the vibrant colors used prior. now the new colors are boring, "lowlighters".

[image: highlight colors, upper before update, lower after update]

Can I crank up the intensity of the notes in any way?